# Get background color of a custom ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I did created a custom ImageView.

I am trying to get the background color of my ImageView in my constructor.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView{
    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }
}
```

How can I get the  background color of the imageview using obtainStyledAttributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Set background
TypedArray defaultTypedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
                                                new int[] {android.R.attr.background});

int color = defaultTypedArray.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```